# How to convert query string to look like sub directories using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How I can change a URL look like this
`http://R/M/adminpages/update_admin_view?ucsuccess&`

To look like this `http://R/M/adminpages/update_admin_view/ucsuccess`

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^/?ucsuccess/([^/d]+)/?$ update_admin_view?ucsuccess=$1
```

but no change happen.

Comment: The rewrite rule you show looks nothing like the URL you say you're trying to match - it would match a URL like `http://example.com/csuccess/abcde/` Also, remember that rewrite rules do not make ugly URLs pretty, they make pretty URLs work: Apache sees what you type into the browser (the pretty version), and you tell it how to convert that to be useful to your application (the ugly version).

Comment: By mistake I paste the wrong RewriteRule can you check it now please

Answer (score 0):

The example still doesn't match up (you don't show anything after "ucsuccess" in your examples, but your rewrite rule clearly expects something) but let's look at what you've got:

```
^/?ucsuccess/([^/d]+)/?$
```

Firstly, `^` means "match only at the beginning". Since your example has `/adminpages/update_admin_view/` at the beginning, this isn't what you want. Delete the `^` to allow it to match anywhere in the URL, or add in the  `/adminpages/update_admin_view/` to match specifically.

Secondly, `[^/d]` means "match anything except `/` or `d`", which probably isn't what you want. You're probably thinking of `\d` which means "any digit". The clearest way to write "anything other than a digit" is `[^0-9]` meaning "anything not in the range 0 to 9".